# Deployed django-vite project experiencing 403 error for all the axios calls

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, cors, vite

I am building a monolith platform of django backend and vue frontend with vite (django-vite). For authentication, I am using session authentication on django side and vue can get user info by djoser or template props (?).

When in DEV mode (localhost:8000 for django server and localhost:5173 for vue), no issues of any axios calls(GET, POST, PATCH etc...) to django backend. After building the vue files with css, I placed them in Nginx reverse proxy server. All of the axios calls have been rejected with 403 errors. If I typed the api address on browser address window, DRF is working fine.

Originally, I did not use corsheader library because django and vue share same origin. I installed corsheader to allow everything. Nothing works after so many tries.

What could be a solution? Please help me out...